# Scale DOWN to fit older iphones

Tags: iphone, xcode, html, cordova

Here is a tricky question: I have developed an app in HTML 5 that uses, I know it is foolish and wrong, HARD-CODED values for image sizes and positions.  I sized it to work well on a fairly low resolution Android. All my images are 540X300.  This fits on an older droid and has room to spare on a more recent HTC and on a tablet it sits in the corner.

Attempting to publish this on the iPhone presents a challenge, because I find that only the newest iPhone 5 displays my app nicely.  The older phones (at least the simulators!) crop my app (well it is html!).

So I am wondering: Can I 'scale' my app DOWN to fit on an older iphone simply by applying some magic to the xib that I don't currently understand?  Is there another way?  Or should I just thank my stars that I can run on the iphone5?

Oh yeah. I am using Cordova/Phonegap.

Comment: please help!  I already have a tumbleweed badge, I don't need another one! ;}D